# xml to php not parsing info correctly

Tags: php, xml

I am using the iTunes API.

And I need to grab the image to parse into our php.

ok.

1. this is from the itunes XML

   ```
               <image height="55">http://a5.mzstatic.com/us/r1000/078/Music/3c/40/58/mzi.ryeiepvk.55x55-70.jpg</image>

               <image height="60">http://a4.mzstatic.com/us/r1000/078/Music/3c/40/58/mzi.ryeiepvk.60x60-50.jpg</image>

               <image height="170">http://a3.mzstatic.com/us/r1000/078/Music/3c/40/58/mzi.ryeiepvk.170x170-75.jpg</image>
   ```

Now I have this in my PHP.

```
$image=$songinfo->image;
                        echo "<li>
                                <img class='minivideo-img' src=",$image,">
```

This works great, but its NOT pulling in the image I want its defaulting to the smallest.

I need to grab the image that is in the xml like:

```
<image height="170">
```

When I inspect my html i see this:

```
<img class="minivideo-img" src="http://a5.mzstatic.com/us/r1000/078/Music/3c/40/58/mzi.ryeiepvk.55x55-70.jpg">
```

I need to get this:

```
<img class="minivideo-img" src="http://a3.mzstatic.com/us/r1000/078/Music/3c/40/58/mzi.ryeiepvk.170x170-75.jpg">
```

Comment: What XML parser are you using?

Comment: Simplexml because it seemed simplest to use and is built into php5

Comment: Knowing Apple, you probably need to use the proprietary iXML parser because they rotated the angled brackets 90 degrees for no good reason

Comment: hmm I dont get it, its frustrating. Perhaps I should delete this question and start again, I was gonna throw up an online demo. But people prefer everything on here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your sample code needs to retrieve the attribute from image node from the XML (in this case, `$mysongs`). Since `$songinfo->image` appears to be the image URL, the `height` attribute should be `$songinfo->image['height']`

[Simple XML](http://au.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php)

**Update:** Now that you have updated your question, you appear to have *multiple* `image` nodes. You need to loop through them something like this:

```
for( $i = 0; $i < count($songinfo->image); $i ) {
    if( $songinfo->image[$i]['height'] >= 170 ) {
         $image = $songinfo->image[$i];
         break;
    }
}
echo '<img src=\''.$image.'\' />';
```

(Also updated to use the simpler attribute notation.)

You know, that link to thinkvitamin.com already had all you needed to know.

Comment: hmm, I dont get it. The data within the xml is: <image height="170">http://anyurl.jpg</image> so how do I do the php ?

Comment: This is the answer just dont understand how to build the php string

Comment: Ah... so there are multiple `image` nodes? This was a crucially important piece of information! In that case, `$songinfo->image` will look like an array. You need to loop through it until you find the `height` attribute you want.

Comment: Cheers mate, i didnt know if i could use child. Will keep plodding away.

Comment: I think I am cocking up my loop, somehow. Have selected your answer and will have to ask one of my php co-worker dudes to have a look at my code. Many thanks :)

Comment: FIXED ! Ahhh just needed to use preg replace, and loop it thru. Cheers mate :)

Comment: I personally don't see why you need preg_replace, but I don't know what the whole XML looks like. At least you made it work.